# echo $Variable . "word" (only returning $Variable, NOT "word") -TERNARY Operators

Tags: php, variables, ternary-operator

Could it be that I'm missing something very obvious here?

How is it that `print ucwords(strtolower($keycode)) . " Preview Page"` only returns the `$keycode` as title, but not the trailing " **Preview Page**" that's supposed to be there too?

```
<?php
$title = ((isset($keycode)) ? print ucwords(strtolower($keycode)) . " Preview Page" : print "Home Page"); ?>

<title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
```

I've even tried `print ucwords(strtolower($keycode . ' Preview Page'))` just to work it in there, but that didn't change anything. It only seems to see the variable...

Does anybody know how to get this to work? **:o)** Help please? Thank you for your time.

Comment: You are missing a `?` in `<php`.

Comment: Oh yeah, but on the code on my page it is there, this one I just typed here & missed it. Thanks, I'll edit that :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the problem is that you are echoing the result of a call to `print` which is just an `int` I think... Anyway, `print` and `echo` both have the effect of outputting the string. You just need to lose the `print`s so:

```
$title = ((isset($keycode)) ? ucwords(strtolower($keycode)) . " Preview Page" : "Home Page"); ?>
```

Comment: Yes, `print` does return `int`, see [PHP: print - manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print.php)

Answer (score 2):

You're using the operator incorrectly. The result of the first expression determines whether expression 1 or expression 2 is returned to the variable or function it is passed to.

```
print (isset($keycode)) ? ucwords(strtolower($keycode)) . " Preview Page" : "Home Page";
```

Comment: Thanks, I was so glad to see a response! Anyway, after using your code my title now returns the number "**1**" instead, it's really odd.

Did you mean that I make that code into the variable **$title**? e.g. `$title = YOUR CODE`? Coz that's what I did with it

Comment: @Love: Lose the `print`.  You're doing `$title = print ...`, then `echo $title`.  `print` echos to the screen, then returns 1.

Comment: In this case scenario, should I mark this answer correct? Or the one below this? Not sure what to do...

Comment: Well, if they are both correct, just pick the one which you think is most clear and more likely to help people in the future asking a similar question.